# Decrypting an encrypted String with RSA

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I'm trying to allow a user to input data that was already been encrypted with my system, but when I try to do this I get a java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null input buffer exception.

The code runs fine when the cipher text is generated through the encrypt method but not when I try to manually change the input.

The method I'm calling to decrypt the text

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(10);
    // Decrypt the cipher text using the private key.
    // Decrypt the cipher text using the private key.
    inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(PRIVATE_KEY_FILE));
    final PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) inputStream.readObject();
    String[] decryptedText = new String[cipherText.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < cipherText.length; i++) {

        decryptedText[i] = decrypt(cipherText[i], privateKey); LINE RSA 217
        sb.append(decryptedText[i]);
        sb.append(" ");
    }
    g = sb.toString();
```

The decrypt method being called

```
byte[] dectyptedText = null;
    try {
        // get an RSA cipher object and print the provider
        final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        dectyptedText = cipher.doFinal(text); LINE RSA:136

    } catch (InvalidKeyException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | BadPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException | NoSuchPaddingException ex) {
    }

    return new String(dectyptedText);
```

Where I getting the encrypted text from

```
String a = "[B@7fc7efa0 [B@1f4532ea [B@7811b0af [B@5166eebe [B@3cc425b2 [B@7186e848 [B@4ffc0932 ";
        byte[][] ab;
       ab = new byte[a.length()][];
       rsaInstance.setCipherText(null);
        rsaInstance.setCipherText(ab);
        rsaInstance.no(); LINE ENCRRYPTIONFRMAE 721
```

This is the exception that appears.

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null input buffer
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2082)
    at finalhandin.RSA.decrypt(RSA.java:136)
    at finalhandin.RSA.no(RSA.java:217)
    at finalhandin.EncryptionFrame.btnDecryptPanelActionPerformed(EncryptionFrame.java:721)

Method to call encrypt

```
   try {
        // Check if the pair of keys are present else generate those.
        if (!areKeysPresent()) {
            // Method generates a pair of keys using the RSA algorithm and stores it
            // in their respective files
            generateKey();
        }

        String[] splited = originalText.split("\\s+");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        inputStream = null;

        // Encrypt the string using the public key
        inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(PUBLIC_KEY_FILE));
        final PublicKey publicKey = (PublicKey) inputStream.readObject();
        cipherText = new byte[splited.length][];
        for (int i = 0; i < splited.length; i++) {
            cipherText[i] = encrypt(splited[i], publicKey);
            System.out.println(cipherText[i]);
            sb.append(cipherText[i]);
            sb.append(" ");
        }
        encryptedText = sb.toString();
```

the encrypt method

```
  byte[] cipherText = null;
    try {
        // get an RSA cipher object and print the provider
        final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
        // encrypt the plain text using the public key
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        cipherText = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes());
    } catch (InvalidKeyException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | BadPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException | NoSuchPaddingException e) {
    }
    return cipherText;
```

Comment: `"[B@7fc7efa0 [B@1f4532ea..."` is not an encrypted anything. It's a bunch of `Object#toString()` output results for objects without their own custom `toString()`.  Where did you get the value for `String a`?

Comment: i added my encrypt method and the method to call it as well string a is the encryptedText value show in the method used to call the encrypt method

Comment: No it's not.  You just printed an array containing members that do not have their own `toString()` method, so you got the default `toString()` from `Object`.  That string is NOT the contents of the array elements.  Please read up on what `Object#toString()` does if it's not overridden in the subclass. For each element you get a type indicator `[B` (Array of Bytes) and the memory address `7fc7efa0`.

Comment: ok i understand what you mean, its been a while since i looked at this stuff, but even if i println the ciphertext in the encrypt method it still gives me the same output with out the tostring. Why is that?

Comment: that's because removing the ToString call does not solve your problem ... your function expects the cipher text as a string ... you have arrays of bytes and you expect that there is a magical way to transform those into a string ... you will have to implement that yourself, if you want something different than the standard implementation as @JimGarrison already pointed out... for example loop through all the elements and convert each byte to a hex string and write those to a stringbuilder

Comment: And remember that you cannot take a stream of binary data (byte array) and convert it to Unicode _characters_ without altering it in such a way that it cannot be converted back to bytes again.  In modern Unicode-based computing it is no longer the case that "characters" (16 or 32 bits) map to "bytes" (always 8 bits) in a trivial one-to-one fashion as was the case in the good ol' ASCII days.